# AWS Cloudwatch logs are not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to fetch AWS cloudwatch logs using aws-sdk.
but logs are sometime available and sometimes showing logs not available.

1st run return 0 messages.
2nd run return 0 messages.
3rd run return n numbers of records.
running again and again to get logs, and after random n number of tries logs are available for 1 time

Comment: How are you using CWL / what are your volumes? If your putting a large amount of data into CWL you could be hitting service limits in AWS. You can potentially increase the limits in AWS - but if your hitting those limits (and your probably spending quite a lot on CWL) you might want to consider a different approach like Kinesis firehose instead of CWL